# Client's DNS response came with the Authoritative nameservers and the client was unable to resolve the DNS?

Tags: networking, dns

I have a scenario where one client PC sends a DNS request to its local DNS server and in response to the request server sent a Authoritative nameservers. The client was never able to resolve the query.

Is it the right behaviour ?

PC sent recursive query to the local DNS server. Local DNS sent a response with below flags.

```
Flags: 0x8583 Standard query response, No such name 
  1... .... .... .... = Response: Message is a response 
  .... .1.. .... .... = Authoritative: Server is an authority for domain 
  .... ...1 .... .... = Recursion desired: Do query recursively
  .... .... 1... .... = Recursion available: Server can do recursive queries 
  .... .... .... 0011 = Reply code: No such name
```

Comment: It would be helpful to clarify what requests were made to which servers and in what direction the responses have traveled. I am a little confused about what queries and responses have been made here. It may be worth quoting some of the actual raw replies.

Comment: PC sent recursive query to the local DNS server. Local DNS sent a response with below flags.

Flags: 0x8583 Standard query response, No such name
    1... .... .... .... = Response: Message is a response
    .... .1.. .... .... = Authoritative: Server is an authority for domain
    .... ...1 .... .... = Recursion desired: Do query recursively
    .... .... 1... .... = Recursion available: Server can do recursive queries
    .... .... .... 0011 = Reply code: No such name (3)

Comment: I intended that you would edit the original question to include this information. The idea is to set up long-term useful authoritative questions and answers.

Comment: So is the request for a domain where the local DNS server *is* authorative, and does the request topic exist on the local DNS server? Basically the local DNS server is saying: Ok, you asked for a name where I am responsible, but that doesn't exist. Which may be the right thing or the wrong thing, depending on if the local DNS server is responsible or not. Or in other words: We still don't have enough information.

Comment: @dirkt Thank you for reply. The local server was actually a part of the same domain ( example "google.com" ) but not actually the authoritative for the hostname ( "docs.google.com" ) requested. We found the issue in the actual authoritative server missing the entry and fix the issue. So my understanding says that the server who is part of the domain but not the authoritative of the actual hostname will send the recursive query to the actual authoritative server to get the IP address of the host ( docs.google.com ) ?

Comment: Very roughly, yes, see e.g. [here](https://umbrella.cisco.com/blog/2014/07/16/difference-authoritative-recursive-dns-nameservers/) for more details (consider caching, and a whole hierarchy of authorative nameservers)..